# Not getting any answer to the equation in my code with my button into my field

Tags: ms-access, button, integer, textbox, equation

I can't get this to work, I'm trying to calculate materials needed for job based on these numbers but when I click on calculate button nothing happens, I've deleted and recreated the button and the field that it should print to...I've tried just printing first line of code to the text box too... I even opened different form, copied it into this form, and changed my button to that form and it worked...so button isn't broken... but the calculate button on the other form wouldn't populate that text box either...I've tried brackets...I've tried passing answer to a different text box...I'm just puzzled...

At one point my box was LSqFt and that wouldn't correct itself so I thought maybe that was problem but it wouldn't go to other boxes either...

```
Private Sub Calculate1_Click()
    
    Dim Wall1 As Integer, Wall2 As Integer, AStuds1 As Integer, AStuds2 As Integer, Roof1 As Integer, Roof2 As Integer
    Dim Frames1 As Integer, Frames2 As Integer, Ptch As Integer, SqFt1 As Integer, LinSF As Integer
   
        Wall1 = ((Nz(H1LX) * 0.75) * 1.15) * Nz(H1Hx)
        Wall2 = ((Nz(H2LX) * 0.75) * 1.15) * Nz(H2Hx)
        AStuds1 = Nz(H1ASX)
        AStuds2 = Nz(H2ASX)
        Frames1 = ((Wall1 * 0.05) + Wall1) + AStuds1
        Frames2 = ((Wall2 * 0.05) + Wall2) + AStuds2
        Ptch = Eval(Pitch)
        SqFt1 = SFX
        Roof1 = Round((SQ((Ptch) / 12) + 1) * SqFt1)
        Roof2 = Roof1 / 2
        LinSF = Round((Frames1 + Frames2) + Roof2 + (Wall1 / 2))
        LSqFt1 = Wall1

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you *Dim* everything as *Integer* which leaves no room for decimals.

You probably need:

```
Dim Wall1 As Double, Wall2 As Double, ' ... etc.
```

Next, you may have to be more expressive (assuming H1Lx etc. are controls):

```
Wall1 = Nz(Me!H1LX.Value, 0) * 0.75 * 1.15 * Nz(Me!H1Hx.Value, 0)
```

Third, avoid `Eval` if at all possible. If you try to convert feet/inches, see my article:

[Convert and format imperial distance (feet and inches) with high precision](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/31931/Convert-and-format-imperial-distance-feet-and-inches-with-high-precision.html?preview=TbXtlf8IKMA%3D)

Also, for rounding, use a better function:

[Rounding values up, down, by 4/5, or to significant figures](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/20299/Rounding-values-up-down-by-4-5-or-to-significant-figures.html?preview=9KH3diMD6vc%3D)

Full code at my repository at **GitHub**:

[VBA.Round](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.Round)

Finally, double-check your secret function `SQ`.

Answer (score 0):

Before I got your response I managed to fix that part, only to realize some of my formulas were wrong but I did get it working by changing some to doubles. Also realized some of the "X" controls didn't exist. By changing my LnSqFt to each individual line until I hit one that wasn't working and fiddling with that one until it did....Definitely going to check those links as I still blanks to fill from that form and 1 in particular has a really tough formula to make it come up with correct answer...and I'm not sure how to get it...

```
Dim Wall1 As Integer, Wall2 As Integer, Ptch As Double, Roof1 As Double, Roof2 As Double, Roof3 As Double, Roof4 As Double
Dim AStuds1 As Integer, AStuds2 As Integer, Frames1 As Integer, Frames2 As Integer, SqFt1 As Integer
Dim LinSF As Integer, EXSht As Integer, RFSht As Integer, StudsH1a As Integer, StudsH2a As Integer

    Wall1 = (Nz(H1LX) * 0.75) * Nz(H1H)
    Wall2 = (Nz(H2LX) * 0.75) * Nz(H2H)
    AStuds1 = Nz(H1ASX)
    AStuds2 = Nz(H2ASX)
    Frames1 = Wall1 + AStuds1
    Frames2 = Wall2 + AStuds2
    Ptch = Eval(Pitch)
    SqFt1 = SFX
    Roof1 = (Ptch * Ptch) + 1
    Roof2 = Sqr(Roof1)
    Roof3 = Round((Roof2 * SqFt1) + 8)
    LinSF = Round((Frames1 + Frames2) + (Roof3 * 0.75))
    LnSqFt = LinSF
    StudsH1a = Round(Wall1 / H1H) + AStuds1
    StudsH2a = Round(Wall2 / H2H) + AStuds2
    StudsH1 = StudsH1a & " - 2x4x" & H1H
    StudsH2 = StudsH2a & " - 2x4x" & H2H
    Concrete = Round(SqFt1 / 52) & " - Yards"
    TrueW = TrueW + 2
    TrueL = TrueH + 2
```

The eval line will always come in as a fraction with lower half being 12, and I need at least 3 decimal places for it to come up with correct figure for the other math calling on it. Aside from that one I don't want any decimals on the other figures...I actually need to make sure some of them on return an 8, 10, 12 or 16 as those are the board measurements and it's supposed to return materials needed for job rather than actual measurements...Does that make sense?

[the form it refers to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHhEZ.png)

Eventually this will be a subform in a larger order form where I'd like it to pass the material list...for now I just need it to get the materials right. The links were super helpful, and I will be utilizing those things as I get the code adjusted. Unfortunately I've only been working with Access for about 2 weeks so my code is all over the place

Thanks again!